# How to disable GNOME3 bottom hotbar

Tags: fedora, gnome3

In GNOME3 under Fedora 21, is there a way to disable the bottom status bar that pops up every time the mouse cursor touches the bottom of the screen?

Something similar to the extension [No Topleft Hot Corner](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/118/no-topleft-hot-corner/) that disables the Activities hot corner in the top left of the screen.

Comment: This was removed upstream (I don't remember if it happend in 3.14 or 3.16 but anyway, there's no message/status bar in gnome-shell 3.18) so probably the easiest for you is to upgrade to current 3.18.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notifications (and this whole bar) have been reworked in newer releases of GNOME, starting with 3.16. That means the easy fix is to upgrade to a newer GNOME release, and since you're on Fedora, that's easily done simply by going to a newer *Fedora* release. Fedora 23 is just out, and, actually, this is good timing for an upgrade, since Fedora 21 reached end-of-life status just a recently, December 1st, 2015.

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I was going to do as soon as I find some time :)